# How do I make error the same size as textbox and label?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I setup a textbox and label:

```
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,74,119,0" Name="txb_idleTime" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162">
            <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="MinIdleTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <Local:NumberValidation />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Label Content="Minimum Idle Time (min):" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,72,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Target="{Binding}" />
```

Currently the error message display directly under the textbox like this:

[image]

What I would like it to look like is this:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify *negative left margin to error textBlock* equal to width of label. This should work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Margin="-160,0,0,0"
           Foreground="Red"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with this Approach: [MSDN Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.validationadornersitefor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I haven't used it yet but sounds as if it fits your needs.